# Sorting a list by data-attribute

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-lists

I have a list of people with job titles sorted by the persons’ first names, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li data-azsort="smithjohn">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="list-name">John Smith</span>
    </a>
    <span class="list-desc">Professor</span>
  </li>
  ..
  <li data-azsort="barnestom">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="list-name">Tom Barnes</span>
    </a>
    <span class="list-desc">Lecturer</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I’ve added the `data-azsort` attribute to the `<li>` element, and I’d like to pop these list elements into an array, and sort based on that `data-*` attribute (using plain JavaScript).

What would be the best way to sort the list by `data-azsort` (A-Z), returning the same code? JavaScript only, no jQuery, etc.

Comment: so where is problem? what is `staff`?

Comment: The HTML attribute is `data-sortaz` in your description you mentioned `data-azsort`.

Comment: you can see [Element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) function

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Thanks, corrected

Comment: Should this work for only one list or for an arbitrary number of lists?

Comment: @Xufox You've already got it but a bonus if can handle more than one list, yes

Comment: Related: [Does jquery `append()` remove duplicate objects?](/q/40909467/4642212).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for any number of lists: it basically gathers all `li`s in `ul`s that have your attribute, sorts them according to their `data-*` attribute value and re-appends them to their parent.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li[data-azsort]"))
  .sort(({dataset: {azsort: a}}, {dataset: {azsort: b}}) => a.localeCompare(b)) // To reverse it, use `b.localeCompare(a)`.
  .forEach((item) => item.parentNode.appendChild(item));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-azsort="skeetjon">
    <a href="#"><span class="list-name">Jon Skeet</span></a>
    <span class="list-desc">Stack Overflow user</span>
  </li>
  <li data-azsort="smithjohn">
    <a href="#"><span class="list-name">John Smith</span></a>
    <span class="list-desc">Professor</span>
  </li>
  <li data-azsort="barnestom">
    <a href="#"><span class="list-name">Tom Barnes</span></a>
    <span class="list-desc">Lecturer</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li data-azsort="smithjohn">
    <a href="#"><span class="list-name">John Smith</span></a>
    <span class="list-desc">Professor</span>
  </li>
  <li data-azsort="barnestom">
    <a href="#"><span class="list-name">Tom Barnes</span></a>
    <span class="list-desc">Lecturer</span>
  </li>
  <li data-azsort="skeetjon">
    <a href="#"><span class="list-name">Jon Skeet</span></a>
    <span class="list-desc">Stack Overflow user</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The funny thing is, it gets all `li`s in the *same* array, sorts them all, but in the end figures out which list the `li` originally belonged to. It’s a pretty simple and straight-forward solution.

If you want to sort elements by a *numeric* data attribute, then use this sort function instead:

```js
// Presumably, the data-* attribute won’t be called `azsort`. Let’s call it `numsort`.
({dataset: {numsort: a}}, {dataset: {numsort: b}}) => Number(a) - Number(b) // `Number(b) - Number(a)` to reverse the sort.
```

---

A slightly longer ECMAScript 5.1 alternative would be:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li[data-azsort]")).sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a.getAttribute("data-azsort");
  b = b.getAttribute("data-azsort");

  return a.localeCompare(b);
}).forEach(function(node) {
  node.parentNode.appendChild(node);
});
```

Comment: Excellent, does exactly what I asked and with very little code. +1

Comment: @Xufox Thank you for your answer. I needed this badly. But I needed it to be in reverse order and a different data attribute but never mind that. Maybe it is a good idea to tell in your answer that to reverse the loaded order you simply need to set `<` to `>` and `>` to `<` which results into:             `return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @purple11111 Actually, forget about that. The better way is `a.localeCompare(b)`. To reverse it, you just need a `-` before it.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting all of the list items, push them into array which later will be sorted?

```js
var allListElements = document.getElementById("staff").getElementsByTagName("li");
var staff = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < allListElements.length; i++) {
  staff.push(allListElements[i].getAttribute('data-azsort'));
}

staff.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a < b) return -1;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  return 0;
});

//Print

document.write('<h4>Sorted</h4>');
for (i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) { 
  document.write(staff[i] + "<br />");
}
```

```html
<h4>Input</h4>

<ul id="staff">
  <li data-azsort="smithjohn">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="list-name">John Smith</span>
    </a>
    <span class="list-desc">Professor</span>

  </li>
  <li data-azsort="barnestom">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="list-name">Tom Barnes</span>
    </a>
    <span class="list-desc">Lecturer</span>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Additionally you can save the index of `<li>` and reorder the `<ul>`.

Comment: Yep, this reorders the 'data' attributes but how can I output the full list again, now based on the new ordering? That is, with the <a> tags, job title, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a comparison function to Array.prototype.sort

you should be able to do something like

```
$items = $('li[data-azsort]');
var compareElem = function (a, b) {
  if (a.attr('data-azsort') > b.attr('data-azsort') {
    return 1;
  } else {
   return -1
  }
};
Array.prototype.sort.apply($items, compareElem);
```

Comment: from OP: _JavaScript only, no jQuery, etc._ Or `$` in your code not jQuery?

Comment: @Grundy Yep, that’s jQuery, but it can be replaced by `document.querySelectorAll`. Nonetheless, it’s missing the `0` return case in the sort function (when both names are the same) and it obviously misses actually reordering the HTML nodes on the page.

Comment: @Xufox, yep, but in answer, nothing about replacing jQuery to something native :-)