# Sort divs using data attributes and JS

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I asked an almost identical question about 5 months ago and got a great answer that seemed to work at the time. Since then I have taken a break and have not looked at so much as a line of code. Now that I have some free time, I am realizing I am quite rusty with Javascript.

Link to previous question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470543/sort-divs-using-data-attributes-and-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470543/sort-divs-using-data-attributes-and-javascripthttp://)

This is my current JSFiddle. jsfiddle.net/wtckhkdq/3/

As you can see I have 4 divs with a variety of data attributes including price, date of listing, and alphabetical rank. I am trying to get the script working so that when each button is pressed, it sorts the divs according to the referenced function. My JSFiddle will not run properly and after looking it over multiple times I can't seem to find what's wrong. Thanks in advance and happy new years to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to include the `jquery` library to use it.
2. In jsfiddle, due to the way they wrote there final output builder, there is a problem with js-scoping, so the functions you created weren't visible by the html block. You can fix this specifically by changing the `function sortDateNewOld (){` to `sortDateNewOld = function(){` inside jsfiddle.

Here is a fix (and everything work)

```js
var divList = $(".listing");

function sortDateNewOld() {
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("date")-$(a).data("date")});    
  $("#list").html(divList);
}

function sortDateOldNew(){
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).data("date")-$(b).data("date")});    
  $("#list").html(divList);}

function sortPriceHighLow(){
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("price")-$(a).data("price")});    
  $("#list").html(divList);}

function sortPriceLowHigh(){
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).data("price")-$(b).data("price")});    
  $("#list").html(divList);}

function sortAlphAZ(){
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).data("alph")-$(b).data("alph")});    
  $("#list").html(divList);}

function sortAlphZA(){
  divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("alph")-$(a).data("alph")});    
  $("#list").html(divList);}
```

```css
.button {
  font-size: 15px; width: 120px; height: 30px; background-color: white; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;}

.listing {
  width: 342px; height: 282px; border-radius: 7px; background-color: #f1f1f1; margin: auto; margin-top: 80px; position: relative; box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);}

.listinginfo {
  width: 342px; height: 64px; border-bottom-right-radius: 7px; border-bottom-left-radius: 7px; background-color: white; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; box-shadow: 0px -4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); font-size: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button class="button" onclick="sortDateNewOld()">Date New-Old</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="sortDateOldNew()">Date Old-New</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="sortAlphAZ()">Name A-Z</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="sortAlphZA()">Name Z-A</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="sortPriceHighLow()">Price High-Low</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="sortPriceLowHigh()">Price Low-High</button>
    
<div id="list">
    
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="listing"
            data-price="99"
            data-date="20171201"
            data-alph="010101"
            style="background-image: url()">
            <div class="listinginfo">
            AAA<br>
            Price: $99<br> 
            Date: December 1, 2017
            </div>
    </div>
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="listing"
            data-price="199"
            data-date="20171202"
            data-alph="010102"
            style="background-image: url()">
            <div class="listinginfo">
            AAB<br>
            Price: $199<br> 
            Date: December 2, 2017
            </div>
    </div>
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="listing"
            data-price="299"
            data-date="20171203"
            data-alph="010103"
            style="background-image: url()">
            <div class="listinginfo">
            AAC<br>
            Price: $299<br> 
            Date: December 3, 2017
            </div>
    </div>
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="listing"
            data-price="399"
            data-date="20171204"
            data-alph="010104"
            style="background-image: url()">
            <div class="listinginfo">
            AAD<br>
            Price: $399<br> 
            Date: December 4, 2017
            </div>
    </div>
    <!------------------------------------------------------------->
    
</div>
```

Comment: Your second point could be misinterpreted as if jsfiddle itself has a problem.

Comment: @trincot, you'r right, good point. I'll update this section to be more accurate :) Thanks!

Comment: @trincot can you check and let me know if you think that it's better now?

Comment: In fact there is an option in jsfiddle that allows you to specify how/when the JavaScript should be loaded. Cick on the JavaScript icon on the top-left side of the script panel.

Comment: nice :) didn't remember that! regarding my explanation - is it better now?

Comment: Well, I would give a different explanation and say it is due to the default JavaScript placement option being "onload", whereby functions are wrapped inside that event handler. It can be fixed by changing the option to "No wrap - in body".

Comment: Thank you, it works on jsfiddle now! Im still having trouble getting it to run on Wordpress... I know thats a super broad issue without checking out my site but any insights into what might be wrong? I seem to remember having to enable JS or something for a past project but I'm not sure

Comment: Yep checked but couldn't find the issue, turns out Wordpress was adding <p> tags before and after my Javascript... thanks though Dekel

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help :) Will appreciate if you can also vote-up the answer once you have enough reputation (1 point is missing). Thanks!