# Questions on sorting HTML DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have below code which works perfectly to sort DOM.

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
     <li data-order="7"></li>
     <li data-order="6"></li>
     <li data-order="5"></li>
     <li data-order="3"></li>
     <li data-order="4"></li>
     <li data-order="1"></li>
     <li data-order="2"></li>
</ul>
<button>Sort</button>
```

CSS

```
li::before {
    content: attr(data-order);
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript with jQuery:

```
const sortList = function(a, b) {
    return (+a.dataset.order) - (+b.dataset.order) > 0 ? 1: - 1;
};

$('button').click(() => {
    $('#list li').sort(sortList).appendTo('#list');
});
```

Or you can check it on codepen:
https://codepen.io/EdmondWang/pen/pozeyXb

I have 2 questions.

## 1. Why does not browser relayout DOM once sort function get called?

## 2. Why `appendTo()` is required to make sort work? (Even there is no detach)

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Related: [Sorting a list by data-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32199368/4642212).

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your first question… the list gets sorted, doesn’t it? What do you mean by “relayout”? I’m also not sure why exactly you don’t understand the purpose of `appendTo`—you need to move the DOM elements to sort them; how else would you do that?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, the accepted answer of related link resolve my questions.